# Entering Sleep state due to 'Low Power Sleep': Using AC (Charge:0%) on iMac

Tags: macos, imac, sleep-wake

My iMac randomly goes to sleep while I'm using resource-intensive apps such as Unreal Engine or Parallels Desktop.

If I run `pmset -g log | grep "Entering Sleep"` I get the following log:

```
2021-07-12 11:17:12 +0200 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Low Power Sleep': Using AC (Charge:0%) 21 secs
```

This is confusing, because my Mac is an iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2014) and of course doesn't have any battery.

I found [another similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404713/imac-goes-to-sleep-because-the-battery-has-0-left) with as only answer the suggestion to reinstall macOS, which I did, but I keep having the same problem.

When the iMac is running such resource-intensive apps, the GPU (AMD Radeon R9 M295X 4 GB) reaches 104 degrees celsius, and the CPU stays between 80 and 95. I'm not sure if this can be the reason, but I would expect a different log if the problem was overheating.

What I've tried so far:

- Reinstall macOS Big Sur
- Reset PRAM
- Reset SMC
- Run Amphetamine to attempt to stop the Mac from going to sleep
- Run Macs Fan Control to force the fans to go to full speed
- Made sure I don't have any hot corners associated to "Sleep"
- Disconnected any external peripheral
- Vacuumed it to try to remove any dust
- Ensured there's enough room behind the iMac to let air flow
- Cleared the iMac from dust with some compressed air (this lowered the CPU temp to ~70 and the GPU to ~90)
- Installed macOS on an external SSD and ran my apps from it

Nothing helped so far. Could someone help me figure out the issue?

Comment: Did you check the iMac for dust? It tends to accumulate over time and can lead to increased heat inside.

Comment: @nohillside I hope you mean 'heat'.

Comment: @benwiggy so do I :-)

Comment: I can't see any dust from the outside, I already tried to vacuum it but nothing came out. I ordered some compressed air cans to try to clean it better though.

Comment: Small update, I bought some compressed air and cleaned the iMac, there was some dust inside and now the temperature seems more normal (~70 for the CPU and ~90 for the GPU) but the iMac still has the same problem :-(

Answer (score 0):

**Try installing to, booting from, and living on an external drive for a while.** I've encountered this same situation and, after extensive debugging, am reasonably sure that it's a result of *specifically* the built-in storage device overheating. (Though, in my case, I was able to swap out the old storage for new storage. I'm not sure if leaving the old storage in will trigger this issue.)

The sleep-reason routing appears to have been obviously incorrectly implemented for this state, as in both of our cases the system was not battery-powered. It is very misleading.

Additionally, your disk is 7 years old, which under average usage is considered very high risk of failure for consumer-grade storage. It adds to my suspicion that the above is taking place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't see particularly high temperatures on the hard drive sensors (~50 degrees IIRC), but I tend to agree my poor fusion drive has quite an age at this point. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: I installed macOS on an external SSD, at first I thought that fixed the problem since I managed to use UE for ~2 hours without issues, but just now the problem occurred again, so I suppose we should exclude an HDD issue.

Comment: @FezVrasta Were you able to disconnect the internal drive?

Comment: No I’m not aware of any way to disconnect it without opening the iMac. But the drive was not in use and the temperature was completely in the safe range